# SQL keep leading 0's in HHMMSS as int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

SQL stored procedure  `sp_add_jobschedule` is expecting the start time of the job in an `HHMMSS` format, as an `int`.  How are you supposed to keep this format when the leading 0's are not present with Int?

I am trying to programmatically schedule jobs to do something 2 days to the minute after triggered.

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366342.aspx#Anchor_1):

> @active_start_time= ] active_start_time
>   Time on any day between active_start_date and active_end_date to begin job execution. active_start_time is int, with no default. The time is formatted as HHMMSS on a 24-hour clock.

Comment: Storing `TIME` as `INT` is a bad idea. Why not alter the proc to accept a `TIME`?

Comment: @scsimon This is a system stored proc - not something he wrote or can control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading zeroes being missing on the `int` isn't really a concern.  In a few examples:

```
TIME       HHMMSS    INT
00:00:05   000005    5
00:01:15   000115    115
00:10:00   001000    1000
01:01:00   010100    10100
10:00:00   100000    100000
19:45:16   194516    194516
23:59:59   235959    235959
```

Each time, regardless of the leading zeroes, is unique, and can be reconstructed to the actual time.  A way to check this is via the following:

```
Declare @TimeTable Table 
(
    Time Int
)

Insert  @TimeTable 
Select  000005  Union All
Select  000115  Union All
Select  001000  Union All
Select  010100  Union All
Select  100000  Union All
Select  194516  Union All
Select  235959

Select  Time Int,
        TimeFromParts
        ( 
            Time / 10000,           --Hours 
            (Time % 10000) / 100,   --Minutes
            ((Time % 10000) % 100), --Seconds
            0,                      --Fractions
            0                       --Precision
        ) As Time
From    @TimeTable
```

---

```
Int     Time
----------------
5       00:00:05
115     00:01:15
1000    00:10:00
10100   01:01:00
100000  10:00:00
194516  19:45:16
235959  23:59:59
```

---

So, don't worry about it being cast as an `int` value, just pass it into the proc even with the leading zeroes present.  It'll still work in the end.

```
Execute sp_add_jobschedule ..., @active_start_time = 003000, ...
```

Omitting them won't cause any difference in behaviour from the proc, but it will cause for confusion trying to read it.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I'm not sure what the problem is.  1:00 p.m. would be 130000.  1:00 a.m. would be 100.  This is equivalent to 000100.  The leading zeroes do not appear in the numeric representation of the value.

If you want to construct the value from a date/time variable:

```
select datepart(hour, @t) * 10000 + datepart(minute, @t) * 100 + datepart(second, @t)
```